# How to retrieve rows from Call Logs with unique number without duplicate

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

How to retrieve numbers from CallLog.Calls table from SQLite(Android)?

for example, if 1234567890 number has 10 call logs in the table, I want the latest one. Currently, I am doing this by checking duplicates in a separate function.

Is there any way to filter in the query itself?

```
String[] projection = {CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 
CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE};

Cursor cursor= getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Comment: Are the times recorded? Show your table schema and some sample data (as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy copy and pasting into a test db)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the response. ya. while answering/dialling a call, time will be recorded automatically. that is default CallLog table by android. I'm retrieving from live CallLog table(Contacts/Recents).

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any way to filter in the query itself?**

**Yes** :-

## Assuming

- column names are callNumber, callDuration, callDate and callType and that the table is called calllog
- that the callDate column is a suitable format (sortable e.g. YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm)

then you could base the query on :-

**`SELECT * FROM calllog WHERE callNumber = '1234567890' ORDER BY callDate DESC LIMIT 1;`**

That is **`LIMIT 1`** is used to return just 1 row, which will be the first row, which will, due to **`ORDER BY callDate DESC`**, be the latest call.

## Demo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  calllog (callNumber TEXT, callDuration INTEGER, callDate TEXT, callType TEXT);
INSERT INTO calllog VALUES 
    /* log entries for wanted number */
    ('1234567890', 30, '2019-01-01 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567890', 10, '2019-01-01 12:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567890', 5, '2019-01-02 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567890', 30, '2019-01-03 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567890', 30, '2019-01-04 10:30','mobile'),
    
    /* other log entries to exclude */
    ('1234567899', 30, '2019-01-01 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567899', 10, '2019-01-01 12:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567899', 5, '2019-01-02 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567899', 30, '2019-01-03 10:30','mobile'),
    ('1234567899', 30, '2019-01-04 10:30','mobile')
;

SELECT * FROM calllog WHERE callNumber = '1234567890' ORDER BY callDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The above results in :-

[image]

## re the comment

> I want to fetch all the call numbers with some other columns in this case.

I believe the following will do as you wish :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM calllog AS x 
WHERE callDate = (
    SELECT calldate FROM calllog WHERE callNumber = x.callNumber ORDER BY callDate DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

- This as can be seen utilises the previous query (but only extracting the one value, the callDate) to ensure that just the latest rows are included via the WHERE clause.
- `AS x` is used to eliminate ambiguities by giving the result set a name and thus x.callNumber is the value from the primary query as opposed to callNumber being the value from the sub-query ( WHERE callNumber = callNumber would always be true and thus exclude nothing).

Note this assumes that multiple calls for the same number and latest date/time do not exist. If this is a possibility then suffixing the code with `GROUP BY callNumber` would eradicate such duplicates.

## Example

Using the above demo table as above with the one exception that `('1234567899', 5, '2019-01-02 10:30','mobile')` was changed to `('1234567899', 5, '2019-01-07 10:30','mobile')`, so as to distinguish the results between numbers.

the result would be :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering... I want to fetch all the call numbers with some other columns in this case. there are multiple entries for each call. But, I want the last one(date DESC). is that possible to do?